# for loop returns undefined

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, hyperlink

I'm trying to create a function that changes a href link depending on what elements are visible.

So in this example I want my link to be [www.link.com/sample1/sample2](http://www.link.com/sample1/sample2).

Because the div sample3 is hidden, it shouldn't be included in the url in this example.

```
<div class="filters"> sample1</div>
<div class="filters"> sample2</div>
<div class="filters" style="display:none"> sample3 </div>

<script>
function rt100_link_function() {
    var link = document.getElementById("RT100link");
    var all = document.getElementsByClassName("filters");
    for (var i = 0, max = all.length; i < max; i++) {
      if (isHidden(all[i]))
        link.href = link.href;
      else
        var one = all[i]
        link.href = link.href + one.innerhtml;
      }
  }
    
  function isHidden(el) {
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(el);
    return ((style.display === 'none'))
  }
</script>
```

The issue I'm faced with is that the url outputs as [www.link.com/undefined](http://www.link.com/undefined) - I just want to take the content of the visible divs and include it within the url, seperated with a slash - but .innerhtml doesn't work?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `one.innerHTML` instead of  `one.innerhtml` like;

```js
link.href = link.href + one.innerHTML;
```

`.innerhtml` is not a DOM Element property, so it always will return `undefined` .

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Helps a lot. It didn't work with the "one" variable, so removed it and replaced one.innerHTML with all[i].innerHTML. Works almost perfectly. Only other issue was that the url included a random string of characters before my intended string. Fixed that with .replace however.